# WordPress - Get posts for each user

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, timber

For a project with students I use WordPress with Timber (TWIG) + ACF

Fot this project I created 3 custom post types : `dissertation`, `subject-imposed` and `subject-free`

Each student can create only ONE post by custom post type (I created a restriction for that).

But now I would like to display a list with the name of each student and their 3 posts.

A list like that :

**Nicolas Mapple**

- Title of custom post type `dissertation` + custom post type name + image (ACF field)
- Title of custom post type `subject-imposed` + custom post type name + image (ACF field)
- Title of custom post type `subject-free` + custom post type name + image (ACF field)

**Brenda Smith**

- Title of custom post type `dissertation` + custom post type name + image (ACF field)
- Title of custom post type `subject-imposed` + custom post type name + image (ACF field)
- Title of custom post type `subject-free` + custom post type name + image (ACF field)

To begin I tried to get the ID of each student :

```
$students = get_users( array(
    'role'    => 'student',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'has_published_posts' => true
));

$students_id = array();

foreach ($students as $student) {
    $students_id[] = $student->ID;
}
```

After to get all posts from these ID :

```
$get_posts_students = get_posts( array(
    'author' => $students_id,
    'post_type' => array('dissertation', 'subject-imposed', 'subject-free')
));

$context['list_of_students'] = $get_posts_students;
```

I got the error `urldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string` and an array but with all posts, not grouped by student

Can I have some help please ? How to group posts by student ?

### UPDATE - better but not complete (solution by @disinfor) :

With the `get_posts` in the foreach I got posts grouped. But **I don't have the name of the student in each group**.

```
$students = get_users( array(
    'role'    => 'student',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'has_published_posts' => true
));

$students_posts = array();

foreach ($students as $student) {
    $students_posts[] = get_posts( array(
        'author' => $student->ID,
        'post_type' => array('dissertation', 'subject-imposed', 'subject-free')
    ));
}

$context['students_posts'] = $students_posts;
```

I got an array like that, I would like the name of the student in each group :
[image]

Comment: Why don't you move your `get_posts` into the `foreach` instead of  using that to just populate an array with ids? You could still use the array, but use it to hold all the posts for each student. That way they are grouped.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was possible. I tried. That's work. But I don't have the name of the student in each group. Only posts grouped

Comment: I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You can include the student's name into the array using `get_user_meta()`:

```
foreach ($students as $student) {
    // Get the first name from user meta.
    $first_name = get_user_meta( $student->ID, 'first_name');
    // Get the last name from user meta.
    $last_name = get_user_meta( $student->ID, 'last_name');
    // Add a new array key for "name". The first name and last name return as arrays, so we use [0] to get the first index.
    $students_posts['name'] = $first_name[0] . ' ' . $last_name[0];
    $students_posts[] = get_posts( array(
        'author' => $student->ID,
        'post_type' => array('dissertation', 'subject-imposed', 'subject-free')
    ));
}

$context['students_posts'] = $students_posts;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I only have one name. This only one name is outside the array of each group of posts and not inside each group

Comment: I think you'll need to change your `$context` - since you are trying to use that to return the posts, but you need to have them grouped. So you may need to put the `$context` in a foreach. I don't have TWIG/Timber to test that.